# executing a batch file but throws an error with LRM00112 multiple values not allowed for parameter logfile

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

This is the export query which i'm trying to run

```
SET PATH=D:\app\clusteradmn\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;%PATH%

SET MYDATE=%DATE%

expdp sfmsbr/******** tables=SQD_SFMS_QM_DTLS directory=export_dir
dumpfile=SFMSBR_BACKUP_%MYDATE%.DMP LOGFILE=SFMSBR_BACKUP_%MYDATE%.log
```

directory and user permission is all given.

this is the error which i get

> LRM-00112: multiple values not allowed for parameter 'logfile'

Comment: How does MYDATE look like? Does it contain any "invalid" characters (spaces, dashes, ...)? Set it to e.g. 20200925 (for today's date, 25th of September 2020) and try again.

Comment: Thanks its worked... MY date format had a space. so i set my own date format and it worked.